# Remove Lwuit Commands from menu in J2ME

Tags: java-me, menu, command, lwuit, series-40

I'm developing a J2ME Lwuit Application for S40 Mobiles ,When i add a command to the form like Exit in (Qwerty S40 Mobiles), another select command appears at the middle .The problem that a menu on the left appears holding the 2 commands (Exit and select).
How can i remove the select command from the menu?

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to use is the `MenuBar`.

This phrase is copied from the API

This class represents the Form MenuBar. This class is responsible to show the Form Commands and to handle device soft keys, back key, clear key, etc... This class can be overridden and replaced in the LookAndFeel

So I think if you can get the `MenuBar` from your `Form`, you would be able to remove this `Command` too.

[MenuBar API](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/iodocs/com/sun/lwuit/MenuBar.html)

Comment: Thank you but it did not work, i'm using the themes from the resource editor in lwuit, i think when ever a new command is added to the form it will be added too to the option menu list, i need to remove the select command from that option list .

Comment: Ok now I´m understand what you want. Let me see. Otherwise, Did you find this command in the emulator? Did you try it in a device?

Comment: i tried it on Asha 302, and it appears as i told you before on the option list too.

Comment: thank you ,but until now i could not find a way to do that,the only thing which i think will help me is protected List createCommandList(Vector commands) method...but i don't know how..